# class needs to be abstract since its members are not instantiated

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a class rat having parameters "value" and "dimensions". Rat has a member "fitness". I want this member to be initialized by constructor, but declaring this member enforces it to be explicitly instantiated.

This  is a class rat having a member fitness. I have declared but not defined the member as I want to get it through constructor.

```
class rat(value:Int,dimensions:Int){
   var fitness:Int
   def rat(){
      fitness=sol_fit()
   }
   def sol_fit():Int={
      var f=value*dimensions
      f 
   }
}
```

Comment: `def rat()` is not a constructor. In Scala, the body of the class is the main constructor, and extra constructors look like `def this()`.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a really bad design for a class. I question nearly everything about it. But it's easy enough to make it compile: just give the `var` a default value.

```
var fitness:Int = _
```

Now it compiles but the value of `fitness` will remain at default (`0` in this case) because you have defined the method to calculate the proper fitness value but it is never invoked so the `fitness` value is unchanged.

But really, why go through all the rigamarole? Why not just initialize it with the calculated value? Why not `var fitness:Int = sol_fit()` or simply `var fitness:Int = value*dimensions`?

Comment: actually doing fitness:Int=sol_fit() function sol_fit() will be called again and again whenever i will try to access fitness. This will degrade the performance

Comment: and in my actual code its not that simple like value*dimensions

Comment: I quoted it just to make the things simpler to understand

Comment: You're wrong about `sol_fit()`. It will be invoked once when `fitness` is initialized. Accessing the value of `fitness` 100 times, or never, will not change that.

Comment: It will not change the value but recalculate the fitness via calling sol_fit()

Comment: as var a=a+v.fitness and var b=b+v.fitness here it will call the sol_fit() twice. I want it to be calculated once.

Comment: @aqsa No, jwvh is right. Try it: add a print statement to sol_fit and then access fitness multiple times from the same instance.

Comment: @aqsa What you say would be true if fitness were declared as def.

Comment: @aqsazahoor; You're still wrong about `sol_fit()`. The code `a+v.fitness` and `b+v.fitness` does **not** call `sol_fit()` _at all_, not even once.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor is the block following the class declaration, so it is OK to write this:

```
class rat(value: Int, dimensions: Int) {
  val fitness: Int = value*dimensions
}
```

The expression `value*dimensions` will be computed when an instance of the class is created, and placed in the class memory as an `Int` value. When the `fitness` member is accessed, the value will be retrieved from the class memory and returned; it will not be re-computed.

If `fitness` had been declared using `def` rather than `val`, then the expression *would* be computed each time `fitness` was accessed.

If `fitness` had been declared using `var` then the value could be replaced with a new value, and any subsequent access to `fitness` would return the new value.